# How to remove contenthash (hash) from name of js and css files

Tags: typescript, next.js

Google cache updates only one or two times a day and the site is broken on a cached page on any build.
There is a request to avoid a broken Google cached site on any build. So the one solution is to remove contenthash from the middle of the name for js files. And remove hash for css files.

Answer (score 1):

Push the next code to next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
webpack(config, options) {
    if (!options.dev) {
      const NextMiniCssExtractPlugin = config.plugins[11];
      config.output.filename = config.output.filename.replace('-[contenthash]', '');
      config.output.chunkFilename = config.output.chunkFilename.replace('.[contenthash]', '');
      config.module.generator.asset.filename = config.module.generator.asset.filename.replace('.[hash:8]', '');

      if (NextMiniCssExtractPlugin) {
        NextMiniCssExtractPlugin.options.filename = NextMiniCssExtractPlugin.options.filename.replace('[contenthash]', '[name]');
        NextMiniCssExtractPlugin.options.chunkFilename = NextMiniCssExtractPlugin.options.chunkFilename.replace('[contenthash]', '[name]');
      }
    }
    return config;
  },
...
}
```

This code removes contenthash and hash:8 from build configuration file names of nextjs. It is allow to have file names without hash in the build directory for js and css files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).